# Random Number Generation weird output

Tags: javascript

I am trying to use `localStorage` to make a random number generator.

I dont know why but my code isn't working. I've tried everything but I just keep getting confused at to why.

Here is my code:

```
localStorage.setItem("MaxInputValue_Storage",10);
localStorage.setItem("MinInputValue_Storage",5);


function Random_Number_Generation(Max,Min) {
  console.log(Min);
  console.log(Max);
  var Random_Number = Math.floor(Math.random() * (( Max - Min ) + 1) + Min );
  console.log(Random_Number);
};

Random_Number_Generation(localStorage.getItem("MaxInputValue_Storage"),localStorage.getItem("MinInputValue_Storage"));
```

Whats going on?

EDIT:
I expect to get a value from 5-10, but I get a value from 0- 5.

Comment: Could you share your "weird output"?

Comment: is it random problem or a local storage problem?

Comment: `Max` and `Min` are strings

Comment: are you sure? at the top, I didnt give them quotation marks.

Comment: Yes. All localstorage values are strings. They're converted to strings when they're saved. Try `console.log(typeof Max)` inside the function.

Answer (score 0):

localStorage values are in string format, + operator works as concatenation operator if any of the operand is string. 
In your code 
'Min' is "5" from localStorage(it is string), 
Math.random() * (( Max - Min ) + 1) returns Number for ex 4.941 so 4.941 + "5" would be 4.9415 , that's why you are getting values between 0 to 4. Use parseInt to convert that string value to Number so that you will get desired result.

```
var Random_Number = Math.floor(Math.random() * (( Max - Min ) + 1) + parseInt(Min));
```